# How to mock when i create object like the following

Tags: junit, mockito

How to mock listAPiMetrics when my code looks like this

```
List<JSONObject> metrics = new ApiMetricsClient().listApiMetrics(new ApiIdList(apiIds));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not mock that behavior. Because you are initiate your object inside code. You need to inject dependencies via contrutor or somehow. Basically, you need to do **dependency injection**.

Some mock frameworks (like moq from c#) able to mock only interface or abstract types so you need to inject your dependencies as interface which this is the most common way in general. Some frameworks like mockito/powermock allow to mock concrete types too (powermock also can be able to mock private methods as I remember).

Change your code to work as below :

```
class YourClass {
    private IApiMetricsClient apiMetricClient;
    public YourClass(IApiMetricsClient apiMetricClient) {
        this.apiMetricClient = apiMetricClient;
    }

    public [returnType] yourMethod() {
        List<JSONObject> metrics = this.apiMetricClient.listApiMetrics(new ApiIdList(apiIds));
        // other logics and return data or whatever

    }

}
```

Comment: "able to mock only interface or abstract types"  Just this part is not true, we can create a mock for a concrete class in Mockito.  E.g. `Person thing = mock(Person.class);`  I've been doing it for ages.   But you're right everywhere else!

Comment: Somehow I remember it that way, maybe I just to confuse it with moq (from c#) We use it both all the time and switching between languages causes confusings like this one :) I will edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  @EmreSavcı